# Lodash - get array

Tags: javascript, lodash

How to make shorthand of this in Lodash?

```
var t = [];
for (var i=self.pointStart; i<self.pointEnd; i++){
    var el = self.points[i];
    t.push({lat:el.lat, lon:el.lon});
}
map.scaleBounds(t);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a `map` with unusual indices. I would start by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on the array to grab the section you want, then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it into the proper form. Much like:

```
var t = self.points.slice(self.pointStart, self.pointEnd).map(function (el) {
  return {lat: el.lat, long: el.long};
});
map.scaleBounds(t);
```

The lodash methods are very similar:

```
_.chain(self.points).slice(self.pointStart, self.pointEnd).map(function (el) {
  return {lat: el.lat, long: el.long};
}).value();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining drop and take.

```
var t = _(self.points).drop(self.pointStart).take(self.pointEnd).value()
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".